# Hide fieldset if it's child ul has no visible elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to do here is hide a fieldset if its child ul element has no visible li elements.

Example code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.readBtn').click(function () {
  var chapterID = $(this).attr('id').replace(/[A-Za-z_]+/g, '');

  $('#chapter_'+chapterID).slideUp();
 });
})
```

```css
button.readBtn {
    margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="story">
    <legend>
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
            Title 1
        </a>
    </legend>
    <ul>
        <li class="chapter" id="chapter_9">
            <a  href="#" target="_blank">
                Chapter Title
            </a>
            <button class="readBtn" id="readBtn_9">
                Mark as Read
            </button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="story">
    <legend>
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
            Title 2
        </a>
    </legend>
    <ul>
        <li class="chapter" id="chapter_10">
            <a  href="#" target="_blank">
                Chapter Title
            </a>
            <button class="readBtn" id="readBtn_10">
                Mark as Read
            </button>
        </li>
        <li class="chapter" id="chapter_12">
            <a  href="#" target="_blank">
                Chapter Title
            </a>
            <button class="readBtn" id="readBtn_12">
                Mark as Read
            </button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</fieldset>
```

I'm not sure how to go about what I'm trying to do. I read [jquery selector question: do something only if all elements are hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891573/jquery-selector-question-do-something-only-if-all-elements-are-hidden) but I wasn't sure how to make it work with my code. It seemed like that answer was on the right track for what I need but I am lost on how I need to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try utilizing callback at `.slideUp()` to select , `.hide()` `.closest()` `fieldset`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.readBtn').click(function () {
        var chapterID = $(this).attr('id').replace(/[A-Za-z_]+/g, '');

        $('#chapter_'+chapterID).slideUp(function() {
          if (!$(this).is(":visible") 
             && !$(this).siblings("li").is(":visible")) {
            // hide `fieldset`
            $(this).closest("fieldset").hide()
          }
        });

    });
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.readBtn').click(function () {
  var chapterID = $(this).attr('id').replace(/[A-Za-z_]+/g, '');

  $('#chapter_'+chapterID).slideUp(function() {
          if (!$(this).is(":visible") && !$(this).siblings("li").is(":visible")) {
            $(this).closest("fieldset").hide()
          }
        });

 });
})
```

```css
button.readBtn {
    margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="story">
    <legend>
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
            Title 1
        </a>
    </legend>
    <ul>
        <li class="chapter" id="chapter_9">
            <a  href="#" target="_blank">
                Chapter Title
            </a>
            <button class="readBtn" id="readBtn_9">
                Mark as Read
            </button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="story">
    <legend>
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
            Title 2
        </a>
    </legend>
    <ul>
        <li class="chapter" id="chapter_10">
            <a  href="#" target="_blank">
                Chapter Title
            </a>
            <button class="readBtn" id="readBtn_10">
                Mark as Read
            </button>
        </li>
        <li class="chapter" id="chapter_12">
            <a  href="#" target="_blank">
                Chapter Title
            </a>
            <button class="readBtn" id="readBtn_12">
                Mark as Read
            </button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

It will hide the closest fieldset (only if the fieldset has no visible li elements)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.readBtn').click(function () {
        var chapterID = $(this).attr('id').replace(/[A-Za-z_]+/g, '');

        $('#chapter_'+chapterID).slideUp(function() {
          if ($("li.chapter:visible").length == 0) {
            // hide `fieldset`
            $(this).closest("fieldset").hide()
          }
        });

    });
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I wanted to accept your answer but when I tried it, the fieldsets wouldn't hide. But I do like your use of closest and the compactness of it.